# Stop user to download file over SFTP

Tags: vsftpd

I have SFTP server and dont want to provide get (download) permission to the few users.

Is it possible to disable get command for few users?

PFB my vsftpd.conf

```
[root@kbdc-sftp-01 vsftpd]# cat vsftpd.conf | grep -v ^#
anonymous_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_std_format=YES
listen=NO
listen_ipv6=YES

pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=NO
tcp_wrappers=YES
```

Below is th sshd config file

```
root@kbdc-ftp-01 ssh]# cat sshd_config |grep -v ^#

HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV


AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys

PasswordAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials no

UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes

AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS

Subsystem sftp  /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

Comment: Are you asking about FTP or SFTP or both? `vsftpd` is an FTP server and has nothing to do with SFTP.

Comment: try this https://docs.rackspace.com/support/how-to/set-up-sftp-users-in-linux-based-systems/